# HTML Form Data into a JSON file

Tags: javascript, html, json

Having difficult time finding solution way to take html form data and transform it into json file using javascript

Looked many places but unable to find anything.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

 <p>Enter names in the fields, then click "Submit" to submit the form: 
 </p>

 <form id="frm1" action="/">
 First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
 Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br><br>
 <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Submit">
 </form>

 <script>
 function myFunction() {
 document.getElementById("frm1").submit();
 }
 </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Just need to know how to transfer the html form data into json not using php but javascript.

Answer (score 1):

```
function formSerialize(formElement) {
   const values = {};
   const inputs = formElement.elements;

   for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
       values[inputs[i].name] = inputs[i].value;
   }
   return values;
}
```

Add this function in your script and call function like this

`formSerialize(document.getElementById("frm1"))`

while will give you json format of your form data like this

`{fname: "wer", lname: "wer", "": "Submit"}`

Hope this will help you.

Comment: It definitely helps and very greatful. Since Im new to Javascript and just learning would like to actually have context such as calling the multiple functions and is this JQUERY? Anything more on the output would be helpful to me.

Comment: No Its just plain javascript @jmichael

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how do you want your end product looks like, but here's the closest solution without modifying too much of your code.

> First: change your inputs to have "id"s instead of name (or both, point is you need IDs)

```
First name: <input type="text" id="fname"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" id="lname"><br><br>
```

> Second: have your script like the following:

```
 <script>
 function myFunction() {
    let output = {
        fName: document.getElementById("fname").value, 
        lName: document.getElementById("lname").value
    };
    console.log(output);
 }
 </script>
```

Hope that helps.